# Uploaded file to S3 visible in bucket, but shows 'Unknown Error' under Server-side Encryption Settings

Tags: amazon-s3

When I upload files to s3 from my hosted environment, everything works. I can see the file in the bucket, and when I look at the Server-side Encryption settings on that file it looks like this:

[image]

I can also successfully visit the file via its Object URL.

When I upload files from my local environment, I can still see the files in the bucket, but they have this error in Server-side encryption settings:

[image]

When I visit the Object URL for these files it comes back with XML saying 'Access Denied'

Anyone encountered this error before?